# File Object error

Tags: javascript

I am checking the length of my array that reads data from another file that has 313 fields. The alert says [File Object]1, which means that it takes only the first field in the array. My code is:

```
var lengthfiles = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    lengthfiles = files[i] + 1;
}
alert("The total length of the array is" + lengthfiles);
```

Whats is the File Object and why do I get this error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`files[i]` is a `[File Object]`. I'm not sure what you expected the output to be.

Maybe you want:

```
var lengthfiles = files.length;
```

Or:

```
var filesize = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    filesize += files[i].size;
}
alert("The total size of the files is" + filesize);
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. I'm using the File API from JavaScript. I'm just trying to import the files[] array into a data list. It's not working, so I wanted to validate the functionality of the array first. Thanks for your advice

Comment: `files` is a `FileList`. It behaves a lot like an `Array` but it's not an `Array`. Like: you can `files.length` but not `files.slice()`. Something to keep in mind. I like to convert a `FileList` to an `Array` first thing so I don't have to worry about this.